# Is it possible to change value in element without changing state?

Tags: reactjs, textarea, onfocus

I have code like below;

```
class Comment extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const color = "red";
  }
  changeColor() {
    this.color = "blue";
    console.log(this.color);
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div className="CommentPlaceHolder" style={{backgroundColor: this.color}}>
        <form id="form1">
          <textarea onFocus={this.changeColor} className="comment" id="feed" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.."></textarea>
          <button type="submit" form="form1">Paskelbti</button>
        </form>        
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Comment;
```

I have a `textarea` inside `div` container, and I want that when mouse is clicked on `textarea`, to change `div` container color. I have tried many things and all failed. Is it possible to do that without states?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the states? States property was invented for this purpose

Comment: You might get issues with onFocus. Try writing `onFocus = {this.changeColor.bind(this)}. Also, as @IhorLavs said, state is just perfect for this case.

Answer (score 3):

A couple things:

First, the way you are declaring the color in the `constructor`. You are just declaring a local `const` that won't be accessible from the components other functions. The correct way to declare it would be using `this`:

```
super(props);
   this.color = "red";
}
```

Next, in the `onFocus` event on the text area, you aren't firing the function appropriately. Use the fat arrow to do so, like this:

```
<textarea onFocus={() => this.changeColor()} className="comment" id="feed" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.."></textarea>
```

Now... The problem with the fact that you are not using state is that when you are changing the component's attributes, the component doesn't automatically re-render, as it does when you use `this.setState`. So you will have to force it to re-render. Luckily, there is the `this.forceUpdate()` function. So in the `changeColor` function, just call it.

```
changeColor() {
  this.color = "blue";
  console.log(this.color);
  this.forceUpdate()
```

}

here is a working version of these changes:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
        this.color = "red";
    }
        changeColor() {
            this.color = "blue";
            console.log(this.color);
          this.forceUpdate()
        }
        render() {
            return(
                <div className="CommentPlaceHolder" style={{backgroundColor: this.color}}>
                    <form id="form1">
                        <textarea onFocus={() => this.changeColor()} className="comment" id="feed" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.."></textarea>
                        <button type="submit" form="form1">Paskelbti</button>
                    </form>

                </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend updating the DOM manually, nor would I recommend calling this.forceUpdate() - that isn't very good practice with React.

Using setState() is the proper way to get the correct result you are going for. For a small, simple app I think you could get away with doing something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

export default class ChangingDiv extends Component {

  state = {
    bgColor: 'red'
  }

  handleColorChange = () => {
    const { bgColor } = this.state

    bgColor === 'red'
    ?
    this.setState({ bgColor: 'blue' })
    :
    this.setState({ bgColor: 'red' })
  }

  render() {
    const { bgColor } = this.state
    return (
      <ColorDiv color={bgColor}>
        <TextBox
          onFocus={this.handleColorChange}
          onBlur={this.handleColorChange}
        />
      </ColorDiv>
    )
  }
}

const ColorDiv = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: ${props => props.color};
`
const TextBox = styled.textarea`
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 16pt;
`
```

Using styled components you can set a color based on a state prop. Here I am setting the background-color of the ColorDiv to match the bgColor state prop. When it changes, so does the background-color. You could even add a transition duration to the ColorDiv for a bit smoother transition.

If you aren't using styled components you could essentially do the same thing except instead of doing a bgColor state prop you would make it a className. The class name will change as you focus and blur the input box:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class ChangingDiv extends Component {

  state = {
    className: 'red'
  }

  handleColorChange = () => {
    const { className } = this.state

    className === 'red'
    ?
    this.setState({ className: 'blue' })
    :
    this.setState({ className: 'red' })
  }

  render() {
    const { className } = this.state
    return (
      <div className={className}>
        <textarea
          onFocus={this.handleColorChange}
          onBlur={this.handleColorChange}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

If you are still not wanting to set the color stately then you could always do the traditional document.getElementById('#colorDiv') and change the color that way. But this will be breaking the rules of React because you will be manipulating the DOM directly.

Comment: im getting this error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Comment: sorry it wors fine

Answer (score 0):

You can call `this.forceUpdate()` to force a rerender, but it isn't recommended. Its almost always better to just update the state.

[See Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate)

Answer (score 0):

To have a change in your UI, component needs to re-render. To re-render a component either your state or props need to change or you need to call [`forceUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate) *(which is not suggested)*

The problem with your code, you are changing a static value and this change is not reflecting in your component until it is re-rendered. To change this you can use below sample code.

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = { color: 'red' };
}
changeColor = () => {
  this.setState({color: "blue"});
}
render() {
  return(
    <div className="CommentPlaceHolder" style={{backgroundColor: this.state.color}}>
       {/* some other code */}
    </div>
  );
}
```